# Find the total area of ​the pyramid.

Tags: geometry, 3d

The base of a pyramid is an isosceles trapezoid whose parallel sides are equal to $a$ and $b\; (a> b).$ Each side face is oblique to the base making an angle $\alpha$. Find the total area of ​​the pyramid.

Can someone draw a picture to this question? I couldn't see how will be this pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.

Here's a diagram for the base of the pyramid.
As lateral faces are inclined at the same angle, their altitudes are all equal among them, and so are their projections on the base.

[image]